# once we have Provisioing and ESB beside each other in telecomunication architecture , howshould we use them ?

Tags: architecture, esb, provisioning, telecommunication

once we have Provisioning and ESB beside each other in telecommunication architecture , how should we use them ? 
what is the role of each of them?

Answer (score 0):

*Provisioning* is the configuration, deployment and management of multiple types of IT system resources.

A *Provisioning Service* may be build based on an *ESB*. [Talend](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendESBInfrastructureServicesConfigurationGuide60EN/10.+Provisioning+Service) for example uses this approach.

In this approach the ESB is used to distribute the configuration and feature description to the used (to provisioned) services.

There are other resources on the web like [this](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/OR/ESB+Based+Provisioning) you can also google for "provisioning service esb".